# Jetpack Compose does not pass the correct constraints to its children

Tags: android, android-compose-textfield

I tested the following code on a physical phone, HUAWEI GR5 KII-L21, running Android Lollipop.

```
 

@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val metrics = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics
    println("the width is ${metrics.widthPixels}")
    println("the height is ${metrics.heightPixels}")

    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    println("height: ${configuration.screenHeightDp.dp}")
    println("width: ${configuration.screenWidthDp.dp}")
    with(LocalDensity.current) {
        println("dp to px: ${210.dp.roundToPx()}")
    }

    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(70.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Red)
    ){
        println(constraints)
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat is:

```
    I  the width is 1080
    I  the height is 1776

    I  height: 568.0.dp
    I  width: 360.0.dp

    I  dp to px: 630

    I  Constraints(minWidth = 210, maxWidth = 210, minHeight = 210, maxHeight = 210)
```

First of all, this phone is 5.5'' at 1920x1080. Compose reports 1776x1080.
Second, Compose reports a width in dp of `360`, but `Boxwithconstraints` receives a maxWidth of `210` only. I expect it to pass `360` to `Boxwithconstraints` This, when converted to px, does not match `1080`, the physical screen width. Could you shed some light on this?